# IIS PHP using Windows Authentication unable to connect to SQL Server 2008R2

Tags: php, sql-server, iis

I'm running a PHP site using IIS and connecting to a Sql Server server on another computer on the network. I created a domain user that has access to the db and configured the app pool to use that domain user.

I keep getting this error:

```
Unable to connect.
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 28000
            [SQLSTATE] => 28000
            [1] => 18456
            [code] => 18456
            [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.
            [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 28000
            [SQLSTATE] => 28000
            [1] => 18456
            [code] => 18456
            [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.
            [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.
        )

)
```

Not sure why it's using user `'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'` instead of the domain user in the application pool.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got this working by clicking on Websites in IIS, then double click on Authentication, and right click on Anonymous Authentication->Edit, and select the Application Pool Identity.

Answer (score 0):

1.) Install System Internals Process Monitor, if not already installed.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062

2.) Check the monitoring logs to see exactly where the anonymous login is occurring.

That will allow you to diagnose exactly what's going on.